# Do UTF-8 characters cover all encodings of ISO8859-xx and windows-12xx?

Tags: python, character-encoding, text-processing

I am trying to write a generic document indexer from a bunch of documents with different encodings in python. I would like to know if it is possible to read all of my documents (that are encoded with utf-8,ISO8859-xx and windows-12xx) with utf-8 without character loss?

The reading part is as follows:

```
fin=codecs.open(doc_name, "r","utf-8");

doc_content=fin.read()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm going to rephrase your question slightly. I believe you are asking, "can I open a document and read it as if it were UTF-8, provided that it is actually intended to be ISO8869-xx or Windows-12xx, without loss?". This is what the Python code you've posted attempts to do.

The answer to that question is **no**. The Python code you posted will mangle the documents if they contain any characters above ordinal 127. This is because the "codepages" use the numbers from 128 to 255 to represent one character each, where UTF-8 uses that number range to proxy multibyte characters. So, each character in your document which is not in ASCII will be either interpreted as an invalid string or will be combined with the succeeding byte(s) to form a single UTF-8 codepoint, if you incorrectly parse the file as UTF-8.

As a concrete example, say your document is in Windows-1252. It contains the byte sequence 0xC3 0xAE, or "Ã®" (A-tilde, registered trademark sign). In UTF-8, that same byte sequence represents one character, "ï" (small 'i' with diaresis). In Windows-874, that same sequence would be "รฎ". These are rather different strings - a moral insult could become an invitation to play chess, or vice versa. Meaning is lost.

Now, for a slightly different question - "can I losslessly convert my files from their current encoding to UTF-8?" or, "can I represent all the data from the current files as a UTF-8 bytestream?". The answer to these questions is (modulo a few fuzzy bits) **yes**. Unicode is designed to have a codepoint for every ideoglyph in any previously existing codepage, and by and large has succeeded in this goal. There are a few rough edges, but you will likely be well-served by using Unicode as your common interchange format (and UTF-8 is a good choice for a representation thereof).

However, to effect the conversion, you must *already know and state the format in which the files exist as they are being read*. Otherwise Python will incorrectly deal with non-ASCII characters and you will badly damage your text (irreparably, in fact, if you discard either the invalid-in-UTF8 sequences or the origin of a particular wrongly-converted byte range).

In the event that the text is **all**, **100%** ASCII, you can open it as UTF-8 without a problem, as the first 127 codepoints are shared between the two representations.

Comment: @JohnMachin Well, if you count NUL. I didn't, but you can see how it works either way.

Answer (score 4):

UTF-8 covers everything in Unicode. I don't know for *sure* whether ISO-8859-xx and Windows-12xx are entirely covered by Unicode, but I strongly suspect they are.

I believe there are *some* encodings which include characters which aren't in Unicode, but I would be fairly surprised if you came across those characters. Covering the whole of Unicode is "good enough" for almost everything - that's the purpose of Unicode, after all. It's *meant* to cover everything we could possibly need (which is why it's grown :)

EDIT: As noted, you have to know the encoding of the file yourself, and state it - you can't just expect files to magically be read correctly. But once you *do* know the encoding, you could convert everything to UTF-8.

Comment: The ideograms which aren't covered by UTF-8 completely are mistakes. One good example is the Florin sign, which must be represented by U+0192, "latin small letter f with hook". There is no way to disambiguate the symbol-used-for-currency from the symbol-used-for-language. But, as I said, those are mistakes - the intent of Unicode is to represent all languages, and UTF-8 is one encoding of the Unicode character space.

Comment: @Borealid: I thought there were potentially *some* Japanese representations which were deliberately not covered, though I could be wrong. Will edit to be more emphatic.

Comment: You may be thinking of the Han consolidation, where Unicode uses variation selectors instead of distinct codepoints to represent different representations of the same core character. I'm not 100% certain. I think it's worth a mention that you'll be misleading the asker if they were asking "can I open any document with this Python code" - which I believe they were, although I'm not psychic...

Comment: @Borealid: The Han consolidation was part of what I had in my mind, yes. Thanks for the clarification about what the current presented code did - I hadn't expected the OP would think it would just be done by magic :(

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to have some way of determining which character set the document uses. You can't just open each one as "utf-8" and expect it to get magically converted. Open it with the proper character set, then convert.

The best way to be sure would be to convert a large set of documents, then convert them back and do a comparison.